# How to fix the npx gulp command launch?

Tags: node.js, gulp

I was trying to execute the command npm init in the folder with the gulp project. The command returned some errors.
When I tried then to execute npx gulp command I got this message:

> PS D:\Документы\Знания\IT\Fullstack Python\Веб верстка. Продвинутый курс\ДЗ\weblayout-advanced\06_bundlers> npx gulp

> node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1080
> throw err;
> ^

> Error: Cannot find module 'D:\Документы\Знания\IT\Fullstack Python\Веб
> верстка. Продвинутый
> курс\ДЗ\weblayout-advanced\06_bundlers\node_modules\gulp\b in\gulp.js'
> at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077:15)
> at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:27)
> at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
> at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',   requireStack: [] }
>
> Node.js v18.17.1

How to fix the last command launch?

Answer (score 0):

I had to place project folder on the drive C:/ and then execute all described commands